# Confirm is not defined reference error?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Every time I try using the confirm() command, it says that confirm is not defined. It may be important to note that I am programming in the Atom.io IDE and I am using the Script package to compile and run my programs. Here is the program I am trying to run:

```
if ("atom".length >= 6)
{
  console.log("The statement is true")
}
else
{
  confirm("The statement is false")
}
```

Comment: Can we see more code?

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: Have you tried to use `window.confirm('')`?

Answer (score 0):

Atom's script package does not run JS with DOM or browser APIs, including `alert` and `confirm`, or even `window`. You should run your script from a browser instead.

Run it in this StackSnippet, it should be fine:

```js
if ("atom".length >= 6)
{
  console.log("The statement is true")
}
else
{
  confirm("The statement is false")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Atom API provides `atom.confirm()`, see the [documentation](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.12.7/AtomEnvironment#instance-confirm) for details.

**Example**:

```
atom.confirm({
    message: 'How you feeling?',
    detailedMessage: 'Be honest.',
    buttons: {
        Good: function() {
        return window.alert('good to hear');
        },
        Bad: function() {
        return window.alert('bummer');
        }
    }
});
```